# It does not submit page correctly in order to show details of next assessment

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem with my submit. Lets say I have two assessments:

- FGTRE1
- FGTRE2

What is suppose to happen is the user will complete assessment 1 first, submit assessment 1 and then they will be navigated to same page but this time it displays details for assessment 2. To know how an assessment is changed I have this line of code which displays the heading of the page:

```
<h1>ASSESSMENT (<?php echo $assessment ?>) <?php echo $sessionMinus ?> OF <?php echo $_SESSION['initial_session'] ?></h1>
```

So the first assessment it displays this:

**ASSESSMENT (FGTRE1) 1 OF 2**

And the second assessment should display:

**ASSESSMENT (FGTRE2) 2 OF 2**

The problem I am having thogh is that when the user successfully submits the first assessment, it then does not go on to show the second assessment, it still displays the details of the first assessment.

My question by looking at the code below is why after the successful submit of the first assessment is that page does not load up the second assessment contents and instead still displays first assessment contents?

I did include php error reporting and there is no php errors and there is also no javascript errors in error console:

**PHP:**

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
}

if(isset($_SESSION['sessionNum'])){
    //Declare my counter for the first time

    $_SESSION['initial_session'] = $_SESSION['sessionNum'];
    $_SESSION['sessionNumber'] = intval($_SESSION['sessionNum']);
    $_SESSION['sessionCounting'] = 1;
} elseif (isset($_POST['submitMarks']) && $_SESSION['sessionCounting'] < $_SESSION['sessionNumber']) {
    $_SESSION['sessionCounting']++;
}

$sessionMinus =  $_SESSION['sessionCounting'];
$sessionConcat =  $_SESSION['sessionCounting'];

if ($sessionMinus == $_SESSION['initial_session']){ 
    $action = 'penalty.php'; 
} elseif($sessionMinus != $_SESSION['initial_session']){ 
    $action = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
}

$assessment = $_SESSION['id'];

if ($_SESSION['initial_session'] > 1) {
    $assessment .= $sessionConcat;
}

?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>

<form id="Marks" action="<?php echo htmlentities($action); ?>" method="post">

<h1>ASSESSMENT (<?php echo $assessment ?>) <?php echo $sessionMinus ?> OF <?php echo $_SESSION['initial_session'] ?></h1>   

<input id="submitBtn" name="submitMarks" type="submit" value="Submit Marks" />

</form>

</body>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(function() {  

...

myClickHandler = function(e) {
       var ng = $('#num_groups').val();
       for (var group = 1; group <= ng; group++) {
         if (!validation(group)) return false;
       }
       if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Proceed?" + "\n")) {
         $.ajax({
           url: "insertmarks.php",
           data: $("#Marks").serialize(),
           async: false,
           type: "POST"
         });
         return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    };

    $('#Marks').submit(myClickHandler);

});

});
```

Comment: Where are you defining `$_SESSION['sessionNum']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I have the problem. You seem to be defining `$_SESSION['sessionNum']` in `session_start` and only checking for next session in `else`, `$_SESSION['sessionNum']` will be active always.

Try this code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['sessionNum'])){
    //Declare my counter for the first time

    $_SESSION['initial_session'] = $_SESSION['sessionNum'];
    $_SESSION['sessionNumber'] = intval($_SESSION['sessionNum']);
    $_SESSION['sessionCounting'] = 1;
} 

if (isset($_POST['submitMarks']) && $_SESSION['sessionCounting'] < $_SESSION['sessionNumber']) {
    $_SESSION['sessionCounting']++;
}
```